# Subset a complex sparse matrix based on a logical column

Tags: r, seurat

I'm working with a Seurat object, and after doing some quality control I have a column of metadata called `discard` containing `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on whether the row in question failed QC and should be deleted. How do I do this? I have tried all the different flavours of `subset` I can find documentation on, but the only way that didn't give me an error was `subset(object, object@meta.data$discard)` which gives me a matrix of only the rows that should be discarded!! `subset(object, subset!=object@meta.data$discard)` is apparently not possible with this type of object. How can I do this without iterating to make an inverse QC called "keep" or something equally ridiculous? Any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Please add some data, so we can figure it out together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add `!` to get the complement of your boolean, below is an example that discards the first 10 columns in your sample, 1st 10 columns.

For samples, you subset it like a matrix:

```
library(Seurat)
# we use a example dataset
dim(pbmc_small)
[1] 230  80

pbmc_small@meta.data$discard = rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),c(10,70))
newdata = pbmc_small[,!pbmc_small@meta.data$discard]

dim(newdata)
[1] 230  70

table(colnames(pbmc_small)[1:10] %in% colnames(newdata))

FALSE 
   10
```

Otherwise, you can also use the names to subset:

```
id_keep = colnames(pbmc_small)[!pbmc_small@meta.data$discard]
newdata = subset(pbmc_small,cells=id_keep)
dim(newdata)
[1] 230  70
```

Answer (score 0):

So, are you wanting to permanently delete the FALSE data? if so a I think a quick logical test could work.

```
new.meta = meta.data
new.meta[,which(new.meta[,"colposition"] == FALSE)] = NULL
```